# iOS Charts zoom property

Tags: ios, swift, bar-chart, ios-charts

I am using iOS charts library and in my application there could be lots of x axis values for my bar chart view but, I need to show few of them. I have tried to do it with `barChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(12)` though it is causing some weird issues. (Like Bar chart's bar fill all x-axis) Instead of using that function I am trying to use zoom property  `barChartView.zoom(scaleX: 4, scaleY: 0, x: 0, y: 0)` . However, I am not sure how many x axis values come when I draw the chart. In some cases, it's 60,84 or 800. How can I calculate right zoom ratio to accomplish for showing 10-12(any number between them enough for me) x-Axis values?

Comment: Try contacting the owners/contributors by going into `Questions & Issues` section of your [library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

Comment: I have also wrote there but they did not respond yet.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use:

```
barChartView.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 10.0, maxXRange: 12.0)
```

instead of:

```
barChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(12.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, I have also tried to use that one but it had same effect.

Comment: How you fixed this @atalayasa