# iOS Charts zoom into a range of values

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

Is it possible to set the chart zoom to a range of values within the dataset? So currently we have a chart that can display close to 100 values within it. What we're trying to achieve is the ability to zoom into a range of values i.e. The first 12 values within the dataset and then the user is able to scroll in either direction to see the remaining values within the chart.

We've currently tried using the `setVisibleXRangeMaximum` function but that only seems to display the first value within the chart rather than 12. And this may be because the data that we receive from he service can be unpredictable i.e. one value may be 1000 and the next maybe 100,000.

Comment: What is a 'value'?

Comment: Can show us some sample UI or graph what you want to achieve b'cus as per my understanding this feature already there in the lib to show max range of data on single show.

Comment: This answer maybe can help you:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50627235/ios-charts-zoom-property)

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension that will let you zoom into a range of values like this:

```swift
extension BarLineChartViewBase {
    func focusXRange(start: Double, end: Double) {
        guard end > start else {
            return
        }

        // Reset the zoom back to the full chart view, so that the setVisibleXRange call will zoom in to the desired range,
        // setVisibleXRange only zooms in, not out.
        // resetZoom() seems like it should be the right API call, but it doesn't work if the user is already zoomed
        // in closer than the range to focus.
        // zoomToCenter(scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1) similarly doesn't work
        while !isFullyZoomedOut {
            zoomOut()
        }

        let distance = end - start
        // If the distance to focus on is greater than the xAxis maximum, we can't zoom in any further
        guard distance < (xAxis.axisMaximum - xAxis.axisMinimum) else {
            return
        }

        // Set the visible range to the distance between start and end. This will zoom the chart in to a range of that distance
        setVisibleXRange(minXRange: xAxis.axisMinimum, maxXRange: xAxis.axisMinimum + distance)

        // Move the chart to the start point
        moveViewToX(start)

        // Due to the previous setVisibleXRange call, the user cannot zoom back out.
        // Restore the visible range to the full width of the dataset, so that the user can zoom back out.
        // Note: this will not zoom the chart back out; setVisibleXRange will only zoom in, not out
        setVisibleXRange(minXRange: xAxis.axisMinimum, maxXRange: xAxis.axisMaximum)
    }
}

// Use it like
// chartView.focusXRange(0, 10) // Focus on the first ten data points
// chartView.focusXRange(chartView.xAxis.axisMaximum - 10, chartView.xAxis.axisMaximum) // Focus on the last ten data points
```